# How to find the roots of $(\frac{z-1}{z})^5=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Write down the fifth roots of unity in the form $\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ where $ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$
>
> Hence, or otherwise, find the fifth roots of i in a similar form
>
> By writing the equation $(z-1)^5=z^5$ in the form :
>
> $${\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)}^{5}=1$$
>
> show that its roots are:
>
> $$\frac{1}{2}\left(1- i \cot \frac{1}{4} \pi k\right)$$ where $k=0,1,2,3,4$

I know how to do the first 2 parts :

**First part:**

$$z^5=1= \cos 2\pi + i \sin 2 \pi $$

$$z= \left( \cos \frac{2\pi k}{5} + i \sin \frac{2\pi k}{5}\right)$$

where $k=0,1,2,3,4$

---

**Second Part**:

$$z^5=i= \cos \pi + i sin \pi $$

$$z= \left(\cos \frac{\pi k}{5} + i \sin \frac {\pi k}{5}\right)$$

where $k=0,1,2,3,4$

---

I have no clue how to do the third part, Please help.

**How to do the third part?**

*Please note: I am a beginner to the complex world*

Comment: So you have $\dfrac{z-1}z$ to be a fifth root of unity, which you have already got...

Comment: @Macavity sorry, didn't get that.. What do you mean?

Comment: $\dfrac{z-1}z$ raised to $5$ is unity, so it must be a fifth root of $1$, which you already have from part a. All that's left is solving a linear equation and some simplification.

Comment: @TheArtist You're not beginner anymore.

Comment: @Macavity but my first part is $z$ , so this is $\frac{z-1}{z}$ ??? How can they be equal?

Comment: @DigitalBrain I am still :/ I struggle a lot :/

Comment: Call the first one $z_1$ and this one $z_3$ if it helps. They represent totally different numbers.

Comment: @Macavity Thank you very much . These letters are so confusing, because I have been used to $x,y,z$ , where one letter represents 1 number. Complex world is all about $w$ and $z$ :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solve$$\displaystyle \left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)^5=1\rightarrow \frac{z-1}{z}=e^{\Large \frac{i\cdot{2k}\pi}{5}}$$ for  $k=0,1,2,3,4$.

Hence $$\displaystyle 1-\frac{1}{z}=e^{\Large \frac{i\cdot{2k}\pi}{5}}\rightarrow 1-e^{\Large \frac{i\cdot{2k}\pi}{5}}=\frac{1}{z}\rightarrow z=\frac{1}{1-e^{\Large \frac{i\cdot{2k}\pi}{5}}}=\frac{1}{\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{5}\right)\right)-i\sin\left(\frac{2k\pi}{5}\right)}$$ Now, $$\frac{\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{5}\right)\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2k\pi}{5}\right)}{\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{5}\right)\right)^2+\sin^2\left(\frac{2k\pi}{5}\right)}=\frac{\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{5}\right)\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2k\pi}{5}\right)}{2-2\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{5}\right)}=\\=\frac{2\sin^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{5}\right)+i\cdot 2\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{5}\right)\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{5}\right)}{4\sin^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{5}\right)}=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{5}\right)+i\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{5}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{5}\right)}=\\=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+i\cdot \cot\left(\frac{k\pi}{5}\right)\right)$$

So the question is incorrect.

Comment: Wow, Can you fit it in a square inch

Comment: @DigitalBrain I can not understand what did you say.

Comment: Answer will look even nice if you just use a square inch of area.

Comment: @DigitalBrain I am not professional with LaTex. So I will be thankful if you edit it

Comment: What what? :o the question is incorrect? :o

Comment: @AMIR I'd have done it before commenting if it was doable.

Comment: @TheArtist So do you say that I am wrong? You can say the question is wrong with a glance at the $4$, in the denominator of the question.

Comment: How did you write $2-2cos^2 \frac{2\pi k}{5}$ as $4 sin^2 \frac{k \pi}{5}$

Comment: @TheArtist You know that $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$. If you use this theorem, then you will see that $2-2\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{5})=2(1-\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{5}))=2(1-(1-2\sin^2(\frac{k\pi}{5})))=4\sin^2(\frac{k\pi}{5})$. Not that at the denominator is $2-2\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{5})$ not $2-2\cos^2(\frac{2k\pi}{5})$

Comment: Thank you very much :) I appreciate a lot :)

Comment: @AMIR it's not about being an expert, You've been member for 9 months.