# How to find the $5$ roots for the equation $(\frac{z-3}{z+3})^5=1$?

Tags: complex-numbers

> $$\left(\frac{z-3}{z+3}\right)^5=1$$

Saw a similar one here. Cannot understand it.

Thanks.

Sorry, I should have mentioned this earlier, the answer is in cot, similar to [How to find the roots of $(\frac{z-1}{z})^5=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990314/how-to-find-the-roots-of-fracz-1z5-1?rq=1)

Comment: stands $z$ for a complex number here?

Comment: Just compute $z$ from $(z-3)/(z+3) = e^{i\frac{2\pi k}{5}}$ for $k = 0, \pm 1, \pm 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Since for $a\neq 1$,
$$\frac{z-3}{z+3}=a\implies z=\frac{3a+3}{1-a}$$
And 
$$w^5=1\land w\neq 1\implies w=e^{i2k\pi/5},k=\pm 1,\pm 2$$
We have
$$\left(\frac{z-3}{z+3}\right)^5=1\implies z=\frac{3e^{i2k\pi/5}+3}{1-e^{i2k\pi/5}},k=\pm 1,\pm 2$$
Hence the roots are
$$z=\frac{3e^{i2k\pi/5}+3}{1-e^{i2k\pi/5}} =i3\frac{\sin 2k\pi/5}{1-\cos 2k\pi/5}=i3\cot k\pi/5, k=\pm 1,\pm 2$$

Comment: It should be $$e^{2k\pi i}$$ and optionally simplify the last part using double angle formula

Comment: @labbhattacharjee thanks for noticing. An unguarded moment.

Answer (score 0):

By taking $x=z^2$, this can be made into $$30x^2+540x+486=0,$$ or $$5x^2+90x+81=0.$$ Solving this gets $x=\frac{9}{5}(-5\pm 2\sqrt{5})$. Then, since $x=z^2$, $$z=\pm 3i\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}(5 \pm 2\sqrt{5})},$$ which is the solution to the original equation.

Comment: Managed to get the answers (in terms of COT) after viewing the answers here. Impressed with the speed, willingness to help and different approaches to the problem. New to this forum and will participate more to learn and to help where I can. Thanks to all for your help.